# Algebra generated by countable family of sets is countable?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If I have a countable family of sets $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,A_2,...\}$ and construct the Algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. Will it also be countable?

My intuition screams YES, but I cannot seem to construct the Algebra in any clever way. Hints are very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A member of the algebra can be written as an expression using the $A_j$ and the operations of intersection, union and complement, and thus encoded as a finite string over a finite alphabet.  There are only countably many such strings.

Alternatively, induct on the number of operations.