# How this space is separable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{A}$. I have shown that the relation '$A\sim B$', if $\mu(A\mathop\Delta B)=0$, is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{A}$. Denoting $[A]$ to be the equivalence class containing the set $A$, let $S=\{[A]:A\in\mathcal{A}\}$. I have shown that the function $\rho([A],[B])=\mu(A\mathop\Delta B)$ is an well-defined metric on $S$. I only need to show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is countably generated, then $S$ is separable (under the metric $\rho$), that is there is countable dense set.

I think the approach will be like this. Take the counatble generator of $\mathcal{A}$. The field generated by the generator may be countable. Now for every set $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there will exist set $F$ in the field such that $\mu(A\mathop\Delta F)<\epsilon$. But I can't do any better.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The algebra generated  by a countable collection is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235300/algebra-generated-by-countable-family-of-sets-is-countable). So $\mathcal D$, the algebra generated by $\cal A$, is countable. Then we indeed conclude by [an approximation argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra) to prove that $\{[D],D\in\mathcal D\}$ is dense in $S$.