# Showing that $\mathcal{A}$ being countable $\Rightarrow f(\mathcal{A})$ is countable - (Algebras/Sigma Algebras)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, algebras

[image]

For the first question my idea was to show that $\sigma(f(\mathcal{A})) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subseteq \sigma(f(\mathcal{A}))$. As for the second question I am at a loss of what to do there. I have been tinkering with it for awhile now and have not got anywhere. Help on both questions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $\sigma(\mathcal A)\subset\sigma(f(\mathcal A))$, as $\mathcal A\subset f(\mathcal A)$. For the reverse inclusion, $\sigma(A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $f(\mathcal A)$, so as $\sigma(f(\mathcal A))$ is the intersection of all such $\sigma$-algebras, $\sigma(f(\mathcal A))\subset\sigma(A)$.

For the second question, there is a clever argument given in this answer by @Robert Israel: [Algebra generated by countable family of sets is countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235300/algebra-generated-by-countable-family-of-sets-is-countable)